# Ray task is not cancelled

Tags: parallel-processing, ray

I am running task in Ray but I am unable to cancel it; the task is still running from Ray dashboard, noting that run_ray_task and cancel_ray_task are called in separate APIs and no errors. or exceptions found in Ray dashboard nor ray client server:

@ray.remote
def **long_running_task**():
pass

async def **run_ray_task**():

```
task_id = long_running_task.remote()

key = "some_unique_key"
save_data_in_redis(key, pickle.dumps(task_id))
```

async def **cancel_ray_task**():

```
key = "some_unique_key"

task_id_bytes = get_data_from_redis(key)
task_id = pickle.loads(task_id_bytes)

ray.cancel(task_id, force=True)
```

Any clue why is that and would you guide me how to troubleshoot the issue?

I tried to troubleshoot the issue to know the reason but with no luck. I am expecting a solution to be able to cancel a running task in Ray.